# express-openid-connect with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, auth0

I am trying to use this library ([express-openid-connect](https://github.com/auth0/express-openid-connect)) to provide authentication backend with "simple setup" but I am getting a simple error when calling the `oidc` object from `express.Request`:

```js
app.get("/", (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    res.send(req.oidc.isAuthenticated() ? "Hi user" : "Hi guest");
});
```

Of course, I am getting this error:

> Property 'oidc' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.ts(2339)

I have tried so far implementing an interface to replace `express.Request` but I get more errors:

```js
interface OIDRequest extends express.Request {
    oidc: OpenidRequest
}

app.get("/", (req: OIDRequest, res: express.Response) => {
    res.send(req.oidc.isAuthenticated() ? "Hi user" : "Hi guest");
});
```

And now:

> No overload matches this call.
>
> Overload 1 of 4, '(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>[]): Express', gave the following error.
>
> Argument of type '(req: OIDRequest, res: express.Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
>
> Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
>
> Property 'oidc' is missing in type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>' but required in type 'OIDRequest'.
>
> Overload 2 of 4, '(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>[]): Express', gave the following error.
>
> Argument of type '(req: OIDRequest, res: express.Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
>
> Type '(req: OIDRequest, res: express.Response) => void' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
>
> Overload 3 of 4, '(path: PathParams, subApplication: Application): Express', gave the following error.
>
> Argument of type '(req: OIDRequest, res: express.Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application'.
>
> Type '(req: OIDRequest, res: Response) => void' is missing the following properties from type 'Application': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 61 more.ts(2769)

Just in case you ask my app was configured in this way:

```js
import express from 'express';
import { auth, ConfigParams, OpenidRequest } from 'express-openid-connect';

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

const config: ConfigParams = {
    authRequired: false,
    auth0Logout: true,
    issuerBaseURL: process.env.ISSUER_BASE_URL,
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
};

app.use(auth(config));

interface OIDRequest extends express.Request {
    oidc: OpenidRequest
}

app.get("/", (req: OIDRequest, res: express.Response) => {
    res.send(req.oidc.isAuthenticated() ? "Hi user" : "Hi guest");
});

app.get("/profile", (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    res.json(req.oidc.user);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening to port: ${port}`);
});
```

I found some answers before I asked here but those didn't work for this scenario. How should I call `oidc` from `express.Request` object?

Answer (score 0):

We recently switched to `express-openid-connect` and have had to use this method to interact with OIDC.

```
    app.get('/api/me', async (req, res) => {
        const userInfo = await req['oidc']?.fetchUserInfo();
        res.json({
            info: req['oidc']?.user,
            userInfo
        });
    });
```

Comment: I guess you have the non-default `strict` property for TypeScript marked as `false`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently used `express-openid-connect` in my project and, this is how I did it. Basically, I have created a `namespace.d.ts` file in my project root directory with the below code.

```
import { Request } from 'express';
import { OpenidRequest } from 'express-openid-connect';
declare module 'express' {
    interface Request {
        openId?: OpenidRequest
    }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
app.get("/profile", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   const user = req.openId?.oidc.user
    res.status(200).json({user});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Early 2022 when you try to import
`import { OpenidRequest } from 'express-openid-connect';` you get a warning that this is deprecated.

> @deprecated
> use the native the Request interface of express instead; it has been extended > and now includes a built in oidc param.

So you should just be able to do this :

```
app.use(auth());

app.get('/profile', (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) => {
  const user = req.oidc.user;
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any more documentation about this?
I cant find a way to make it work either...

```
Property 'oidc' does not exist on type 'Request'.ts(2339)
```

I've noticed the deprecated warning but it does not help a lot...
I'm using Nuxt2 with Express.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30964365)